# irrlicht collada loader warning: wrong tag usage found: library controllers

Tags: c++, 3d, irrlicht

I am trying to draw a tower in Irrlicht. So far, all of the help and tutorials I have found are for animated objects. I have done several of the tutorials(1,2,4,5,9,12) with no trouble, but when I try drawing a model that did not come with Irrlicht, I get:

"collada loader warning: wrong tag usage found: library controllers"

I am using Irrlicht 1.8 and gcc 4.7.1.

I am new to making things that are not console applications so any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Okay, now there do not seem to be any problems, but that warning still keeps showing up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I opened the model file (created with Blender) in a text editor and found this empty XML tag:

```
  <library_controllers/>
```

Deleting it fixed the warning.

I checked the same file with [COLLADA Coherency Test](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Portal%3aCoherencyTest) and it showed a similar error, leading me to think this is a problem with the way Blender exports .dae files.